# Docsearch on subpath '/docs' not scraping side navigation

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

A Docusaurus documentation website: https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs/ is rendered in [Docs only mode](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode).

The Algolia Docsearch scraper is not scraping root level pages, instead it logs `Ignored: from start url`. This issue only seems to arise when the Docusaurus build is nested under `{baseUrl}/docs`.

Why is this being ignored? This is my docsearch config:

```json
{
  "index_name": "atmoplan-documentation",
  "start_urls": ["https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs"],
  "sitemap_urls": ["https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs/sitemap.xml"],
  "sitemap_alternate_links": true,
  "stop_urls": ["/tests"],
  "selectors": {
    "lvl0": {
      "selector": "(//ul[contains(@class,'menu__list')]//a[contains(@class, 'menu__link menu__link--sublist menu__link--active')]/text() | //nav[contains(@class, 'navbar')]//a[contains(@class, 'navbar__link--active')]/text())[last()]",
      "type": "xpath",
      "global": true,
      "default_value": "Documentation"
    },
    "lvl1": "header h1",
    "lvl2": "article h2",
    "lvl3": "article h3",
    "lvl4": "article h4",
    "lvl5": "article h5, article td:first-child",
    "lvl6": "article h6",
    "text": "article p, article li, article td:last-child"
  },
  "strip_chars": " .,;:#",
  "custom_settings": {
    "separatorsToIndex": "_",
    "attributesForFaceting": ["language", "version", "type", "docusaurus_tag"],
    "attributesToRetrieve": ["hierarchy", "content", "anchor", "url", "url_without_anchor", "type"]
  },
  "conversation_id": ["833762294"],
  "nb_hits": 46250
}
```

Comment: There is something strange inside your `sitemap.xml`. For example the first link is `https://www.vito.be/docs/markdown-page`, but your URL is `https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs`. Maybe the baseUrl parameter is wrong inside your `docusaurus.config.js`?

Comment: Thank you for looking better then me at the sitemap. The problem was the `url` parameter which was set to www.vito.be. I didn't realise the url parameter was used for this.

Comment: I glad that it worked out! And I noted that you deleted your answer too, so I took the liberty to write an answer — maybe it can help others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `docusaurus.config.js` you should set the `url` parameter with the actual website where you will be hosting your docs. Something like:

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs',
[…]
}
```

This will be used by your `docusaurus` to generate the `sitemap.xml`, used by `algolia` to locate your pages.

---

**REFERENCE:** https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus.config.js/#url

---

**DISCLAIMER**

I noted something strange inside your `sitemap.xml`. For example the first link was `https://www.vito.be/docs/markdown-page`, but defined URL for Algolia is `https://slovakia-atmo-plan.marvintest.vito.be/docs`.